# Select elements with data attribute *not* using jQuery

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to get a list of all elements containing a `data-*` attribute **without** using jQuery (and hopefully without iterating the whole DOM-tree) ?

I can find a lot of answers using jQuery but I cannot use it in my project and neither can I find answers using plain Javascript.

For example if I have this HTML:

```
<input data-mydata="data1">
<input data-mydata="data2">
<div data-mydata="data3"></div>
<div data-mydata="data4"></div>
<input>
<div></div>
```

and then get a list of all elements, of any kind, that contains `data-mydata` ?

What I try to achieve is to get data from certain elements for storage based on the data-* as well as the data value.

I know I can use the `name` attribute with `getElementsByName` but that is not possible to use in my project either as the elements have names set for other purposes.

And I believe the `querySelectorAll` only works with CSS (?).

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(['data-mydata']);

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` is definitely javascript. check out the browser support for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: select all elements with "data-xxx" attr WITHOUT jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/javascript-select-all-elements-with-data-xxx-attr-without-jquery)

Comment: @Jack, thank you. Just removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-mydata]');
```