# Is it possible to select all elements with an attribute value greater than a certain number?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wonder if the following is possible with CSS:

HTML-Code:

```
<span class="funny-elem" data-mystate="127">Hello World</span>
<span class="funny-elem" data-mystate="69">Hello Bird</span>
<span class="funny-elem" data-mystate="1337">Hello Nerd</span>
<span class="funny-elem" data-mystate="14">Hello What</span>
<span class="funny-elem" data-mystate="0">Hello Else</span>
...
```

CSS-Code:

```
.funny-elem[data-mystate=">50"] {
    color:#0f0;
}

.funny-elem[data-mystate="<50"] {
    color:#f00;
}
```

The above CSS code will not work of course as the "greater than" and "lesser than" sign are interpreted as attribute value here.

However do you know a way to select all elements with an numerical attribute value greater than or lesser than a certain number?

Comment: In plan CSS no, there's no way to do that.

Comment: At least no easy way but maybe somebody has an idea?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/javascript-select-all-elements-with-data-xxx-attr-without-jquery

Comment: With Javascript its ez however it would be nice to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way in pure CSS.

Possible attribute selectors are:

- **[att]**
- **[att=val]**
- **[att~=val]**
- **[att|=val]**

And [**W3's docs on Attribute Selector**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) adds:

> Attribute values must be CSS **identifiers or strings.** [CSS21] The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language.

So, they're not numeric. There's no way to use any numeric comparision.

Comment: As I just saw possible hack would be: [att^=val] concretly [data-mystate^="1"] to select all states starting with 1. However thats not actually solving the problem why didnt they make an selector like [attr>=val] ?

Comment: Because then CSS would need to know that **val** is a number. And CSS does not threat them as numbers (at least yet) :)

Comment: Well I think they could at least have implemented some possibility for string comparison (greater than). However it looks like I have to accept there is currently no way O:-)

However I just came up with one evil hack - you output the number in  unary and use [data-mystate^="11111"] and so on :-D

Comment: @Blackbam - What is generating this `data-mystate` value?

Comment: its a database number output by PHP. However I know that changing the HTML would change the actual question therefore your answer is correct. I just wait for one more day if somebody comes up with another idea.

Comment: I would sugest you to implement the logic in PHP then. Check if the data-state is less than 50, set a specific class to the span.

Answer (score 0):

Basic CSS3 does not support logic -- it is strictly style.

You could achieve what you want by using Javascript to do the logic and add a class to your `span` if the statement is true, or use a preprocessor for your CSS, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Here's how you could do it with a class and pure Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("funny-elem")
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var comparator = x[i].getAttribute("data-mystate");
    if (comparator > 50){
      x[i].setAttribute("class","funny-elem over50");
    }
    if (comparator < 50){
      x[i].setAttribute("class","funny-elem under50");
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .funny-elem.over50{ color:#0f0;}
  .funny-elem.under50{ color:#f00;}
</style>
```

[View jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L49okp52/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large the threshold is, and how clean you'd like your CSS, you could use `:not()` and `:is()` to achieve this effect — something like the following:

```css
span[data-mystate]:not(:is(
[data-mystate="1"],
[data-mystate="2"],
[data-mystate="3"]
/*, ... */)) {
    color:#0f0;
}
```

I actually [just used this trick](https://github.com/waldyrious/downstyler/pull/91/commits/b757acea8f9668a4781b174618ac83d5cc6f1f66#diff-6317779dbc31c66644b5dda0e1795c413070275659283a468378371f28139a8e) in my Downstyler project to use a custom style for `<select>` elements with a `size` attribute larger than 1.

Comment: Did not know the :is selector, interesting. Of course with SASS you can also easily make a loop here. Still I miss a CSS feature which allows selection on data attribute wildcards or comparison operators.