# How to select div children (4th child) by attribute in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

`

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="box" data-index="1"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="2"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="3"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="4"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="5"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="6"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="7"></div>
  <div class="box" data-index="8"></div>  
</div>
```

`

i want to select every 4n child by data-index attribute *(not by nth child property)*. want **data-index=4** & **data-index=8** should be color blue. how to deal with this.

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Comment: write manually all the cases if you know that your data is limited. You will probably need 5 or 6 selector at most

Comment: Attribute values are strings. You can't create any "numerical" logic with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614630/is-it-possible-to-select-all-elements-with-an-attribute-value-greater-than-a-cer
`div[data-index]:nth-child(4n)` would work, but it will ignore the actual value inside the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you can't do this with CSS, you have to use Javascript for this one:

```js
// If you want to start from the first element then use 0 or otherwise use 4 as the starting point
for (let i = 4; i < document.querySelectorAll('.box').length; i += 4) {
    document.querySelector(`[data-index=${i}]`).style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Hey dev this is great solution but can you help me achieve this thing using Swiper JS (React) ? 
<Swiper
        slidesPerView={3}        
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        
      </Swiper>
I want to add a bg color in every 2th index in this slider

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure how to use it with SwiperJS (I don't use it)