# Get Element Where Data Attribute == Something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery or JavaScript, I am wanting to get an element, or rather, select an element, by its data attribute, then apply a CSS class using addClass to the selected element.

Does anybody know how to do this? I've tried all the different .attr and .prop methods but they don't do what I want, as I don't know the ID or anything of the element beforehand, as it is set dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery selector:

```
$('[data-something="something"]')
```

Or starts With:

```
$('[data-something^="something"]')
```

Ends With:

```
$('[data-something$="something"]')
```

And then you can use:

```
$('[data-something="something"]').addClass(new_class_name);
```

The above will match all the elements having:

```
<tag data-something="something"></tag>
```

And give them a class `new_class_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("p[data-yourdata='whatever']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a native JavaScript method and aren't worried about browser support for IE8 and below, you can use querySelector or querySelectorAll as explained in this answer: [javascript: select all elements with "data-" attribute (without jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/javascript-select-all-elements-with-data-xxx-attr-without-jquery)

That said, if you're already tied to using jQuery's addClass and/or other selector methods it would probably be easier to stick to the selectors outlined above.

This answer gives a good breakdown of jQuery benefits/costs vs. native selectors: [jQuery vs document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503534/jquery-vs-document-queryselectorall)