# Using Javascript to hide elements with specific data-test-id value

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

I often use a simple Greasemonkey JS script to hide elements on web pages - this is a basic one I use to hide some ads on Yahoo Mail which are in DIVs with a specific ID:

```
function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle(" #slot_LREC, #slot_LREC4 { display:none; }");
```

The issue I have is that quite a lot of content in Yahoo Mail doesn't have a generic Class or ID, but instead has a `data-test-id` value - e.g.

```
<a data-test-id="pencil-ad" class="something_very_complicated">example</a>
```

I wondered if there's any way to create a variant of the addGlobalStyle function to hide elements where an element has a specific `data-test-id` value?

I don't have the option of using jQuery - or at least, I don't know how to add jQuery into the GM script...

As far as I can tell, this isn't a duplicate of [javascript: select all elements with "data-" attribute (without jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/javascript-select-all-elements-with-data-attribute-without-jquery) because I am trying to hide only one element where the data-test-id attribute has a certain value. I'm not trying to hide all elements which have a data-test-id attribute.

Comment: Just use an attribute selector in your css rule set. `[data-test-id] { display: none; }` will hide all elements with that attribute.

Comment: For hide/show see [**JavaScript hide/show element**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select based on attributes like this.

I'm selecting all the elements with `data-test-id=cheese` and then I'm using a `for of` to hide them.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-id=cheese]');

for (let element of elements) {
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background: tomato;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">7</div>
<div>8</div>
```

You can, of course, do this without any javascript too by adding this bit of CSS

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background: tomato;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

[data-test-id=cheese] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div data-test-id="cheese">7</div>
<div>8</div>
```

Both snippets do the same thing.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: It is very helpful, thank you very much Andrew!