# Clicking on an attribute in the table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please help i want to click this via javascript. How do you refer to this selected attribute?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to write a CSS selector for that attribute? If so, `'[data-day="03.06.2020"]'`. If not, what are you asking?

Comment: That's how I want to click it using javascript
how to write "Click" syntax for this element? document.getElementBy ...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all elements with "data-" attribute without using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/select-all-elements-with-data-attribute-without-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('[data-day="03.06.2020"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
const element = document.querySelectorAll('[data-day="03.06.2020"]');
console.log(element)
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pure JavaScript solution:

```js
document.querySelector("[data-day='03.06.2020']").click();
```

Otherwise, if you have the JQuery library, use this:

```js
$("[data-day='03.06.2020']").click();
```

I recommend using the [3.2.1 JQuery Library](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't have a jquery library ... How do you write it in plain js?

Comment: @Majkel36 I updated my answer for a pure JavaScript solution.