# How can I hide element with the data-xxx attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide a div but just the div with a special data-xxx.

```
<div data-platform="dinner"  class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-platform="lunch"  class="product">lunch</div>
```

ATTENTION:

I want to hide all data-platform which are "dinner".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all elements with a "data-xxx" attribute without using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084557/select-all-elements-with-a-data-xxx-attribute-without-using-jquery)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava this question was not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl look a little closer at that title :)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, which means pure JS which is what the dupe provides

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava because i just want to hide the data-platform lunch and dinner should be visible

Comment: @NilsVonBismarck How is the `data-platform` getting shown right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pure CSS

You could set the `display` to `none` for a "data-attribute" of `platform` that equals `"dinner"`.

```css
div[data-platform="dinner"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-platform="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-platform="lunch" class="product">Lunch</div>
```

### With JavaScript

Filter all the `<div>` elements with the `platform` "data-attribute", filter the ones that have a value of `"dinner"`, and add a `.hidden` class to them.

```js
const form = document.forms['choice-form'];

const isSelectionEmpty = select =>
  (vals => vals.length === 0 || (vals.length === 1 && vals[0] === ''))
  (selectedValues(select));

const selectedValues = select =>
  [...select.selectedOptions].map(({ value }) => value);

const handleMealChange = e => {
  const
    isEmpty = isSelectionEmpty(e.target),
    allowList = selectedValues(e.target);
    
  document.querySelectorAll('div[data-platform]')
    .forEach(div =>
      div.classList.toggle('hidden', !isEmpty &&
        !allowList.includes(div.dataset.platform)));
};

form.elements.meal.addEventListener('change', handleMealChange);

// Alternatively
//document.querySelector('select[name="meal"]')
//  .addEventListener('change', handleMealChange);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="choice-form">
  <select name="meal" multiple>
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
    <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
  </select>
</form>
<hr />
<div data-platform="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-platform="lunch" class="product">Lunch</div>
```

Comment: I want to do it with JS

Comment: No need to use `filter` when you can specify the value in the selector... Also, that's the same as the answers to the proposed duplicate.

Comment: When I have like 5 things for the datalist and I choose one how can I hide all but not this one which I have selected? @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: @NilsVonBismarck What is to be shown and what is to be hidden?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl e.g. I have 3 of the divs and each of them with different content and I select one of them e.g. in a selecter and I just want to see the div with this content. Like 3 div with food, fun, drink and I choose fun and I just see fun.

Comment: @NilsVonBismarck You can use an "allow list" to tell the application which things to display. This list can be derived from a `<select multiple>` element's value.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I have a selecter but I want that I can read this selecter and just show the selected word

Comment: Huuuuuuuge thanks @Mr.Polywhirl . But one little question if its okay. When I have more than one element with e.g. lunch how does it works?

Comment: @NilsVonBismarck If the first option is selected (no choice), all will show, but once you select one or more items, any item in that selection will be shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230819/discussion-between-nilsvonbismarck-and-mr-polywhirl).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I know I know but when I take your code there gets the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined" but why there is a form?

Comment: @NilsVonBismarck I wrapped by `<select>` in a `<form>`, because it is proper HTML markup to encapsulate `<input>` and `<select>` elements within a `<form>`. This could start a flame war, so I will leave you with this: [_"Is <input> well formed without a <form>?_"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294572/is-input-well-formed-without-a-form). Anyways, I added an alternative selector for you, in the case where you do not have a `<form>`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Sorry there is a typo i mean why there comes a error when there is a form

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I know its okay but look at this I copied your code but there its not working. https://codepen.io/NilsTheDev/pen/YzNxJVg

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-platform="dinner" class="product">Dinner</div>
<div data-platform="lunch" class="product">Lunch</div>
```

> I want to hide all data-platform which are "dinner".

**JQuery Solution:**

```
$('.product').each(function(){
  var sData = $(this).data('platform');
  if(sData == 'dinner'){
     $(this).hide();
  }

});
```